# Xamarin Forms Android - Prevent android to recycle the app when app is backgrounded

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

If you change app to another one and go back, everything is preserved, scroll position, loaded page, everything.

But if you spend some time on other apps, and then go back, the app loads again because android recycled the memory.

Since this app is meant to be switching apps looking for information.
Is there a way to ask android to prevent that?

thanks a lot

Comment: You could maybe look into background work on Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: The ultimate answer is "You should not rely on being preserved". When app goes to background, serialize to a file information describing what needs to be preserved. When app resumes, read that file, and recreate the UI, if it has been discarded. The primary way to not be recycled, is to minimize resources used by app when it is backgrounded. Discard anything you can easily reload. (This is a use case where Xamarin Forms is not ideal, because it inherently has a larger memory footprint than a Xamarin.Android or native app.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code?